# ngIf not working

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

I'm using ngIf in a parent template. There I have the following code.

In html:

```
<button *ngIf="saveButton" type="button" class="button-success" (click)="save()">Save</button>
<add (setSavebutton)="setSavebutton($event)"></add>
```

In the component:

```
private setSavebutton(_boolean: any) {
    this.saveButton = _boolean;
    console.log(this.saveButton);  // true
}
private save() { // save my item set by child }
```

In my child (add) I do:

```
@Output() setSavebutton: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

 if (this.form.valid) {
        console.log(this.form.valid); // true
        this.setSavebutton.emit(true);
    }
```

Both console.log return **true** but my button is not showing.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I found a work around.. They code of the child is the same.

In parent html:

```
<button [hidden]="!saveButton" type="button" class="button-success" (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

Why does the **hidden** work and the **ngIf** not?

Comment: `(click)="save()"` calls `save()`, but there is no `save()` method.

Comment: There is it's not important. It's about the button not showing. I'm not going to add all my code you not going to be happy.

Comment: You could add the relevant code, or adjust your code so that it makes sense for us here. Where do you call `setSaveButton()` from?

Comment: This is not a reactive form but yeah it should work like this :S But sadly it doesn't..

Comment: It load data in the form if the form (formbuilder with required validator) is valid it will enable the button for submit on the parent.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question where you code is called from.
A general workaround:

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}

private setSavebutton(_boolean: any) {
    this.saveButton = _boolean;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    console.log(this.saveButton);  // true
}
```

With more information, it could be possible to suggest how to fix the root cause.

Comment: I edited my question a little but it seems [hidden] works.

Comment: "Still not answer the questions", that's because the question doesn't provide enough information. I assume code that runs outside Angulars zone calls your `setSaveButton()` method. Angular doesn't get notified that a change detection cycle is due, and therefore doesn't update bindings.

Comment: It run with an @Output on the Child. And it didn't solve it btw. It will mess up and refresh the data with wrong data.